# Wrong ubuntu installation does not recognizes windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I had a dual boot installation ubuntu+windows that work just nice, but i messed up with ubuntu so much that i needed to reinstall it, and for some other reasons too, reinstallig was a good idea, so I did it. No I can not access windows because it does not shows up on grub. Already runned boot-repair but nothing. It seems that before reinstalling i should deleted the linux partition from windows and let the windows bootleader  be the only one. How can I fix this problem? I've found pre installation instrunctions.

Thanks in advance.

Ubuntu 14.04

-- Edit --

Some details

Step 1. Be happy with ubuntu installed along side with windows

Step 2. Be bored so that I wanted to play arround ending up on screwing the ubuntu installation

Step 3. Care little about the installed OS and be so lazy to fix it so re install the ubuntu OS

Step 4. Finish installation all stuff required and notice that grub does not load your previous installation of windows (I didn't delete it.. just in case)

Step 5. Search the problem and found a lot of places saying that before re installing ubuntu you have to let windows be the boot loader so that ubuntu installation will detect it... (too late)

Step 6. Ask ubuntu :) (Solved by the way)

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The out put of the command above, it is solved, but i have two entries for windows 8, would need another question maybe thought

```
Disco /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 60801 cilindros, 976773168 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x9d5a16ba

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          720894   209717247   104498177    5  Extendida
La partición 2 no se inició en el limite físico del sector
/dev/sda3       209717248   976771071   383526912    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5          720896     4671487     1975296   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6         4673536   209717247   102521856   83  Linux
```

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear, could you edit it and tell us what you did step by step.

Comment: Run `sudo fdisk -l` and add this information to your question.

Comment: Kind of same idea but the other way around, and the solution is simplier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run at Ubuntu's terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

...and your Windows installation will be on Grub's list again...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Read this official [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) from ubuntu. This might just be the fix you need.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ah. Great reference. I'll make note of this for future answers.